# Automorphism of power series and Jacobian matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, formal-power-series

I have seen it claimed, for example [here](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ettm/jacobian.html) (in the case $n=2$) that if $k$ is a field and $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ all of which have zero constant coefficient, the homomorphism

$$\phi: k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]] \to k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]] $$
$$ \phi(x_i) = f_i$$

is an isomorphism if and only if
$$\det\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right)_{i,j} $$
is invertible i.e. has non-zero constant coefficient.

I am primarily interested in a ***reference*** where I can find a  proof of this result.

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308583/substitution-homomorphism-in-formal-power-series-ring-being-a-ring-isomorphism), but it is marked as a duplicate and the link to the question which it is a duplicate of is dead.

---

Partial progress: Surjectivity is not too difficult. Let
$$J(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right)  $$
and let $H(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be the inverse matrix.
Then
$$\sum_{j=1}^n H_{ij}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_i + \text{ higher order terms }$$
Then we can make successive higher-order corrections to get an expression for $x_i$. Hence, $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are in the image of the map $\phi$.

Comment: The duplicate has been updated - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225740/the-group-of-k-automorphisms-of-kx-y-k-is-a-field) for the original answer which contains a full solution. (I thought the site would not allow deletion of an intermediate entry in a chain of duplicates, but apparently it can happen sometimes.)

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for linking to the original question. Would it be appropriate to delete my question, given that it isn't adding much to the site?

Comment: If your question is answered fully, then sure, feel free to delete. If there's something that's still unanswered, I would recommend editing your post to make that clear.